# Replace TextBox with a CHECKBOX USING getElementsByName

Tags: javascript, html

I have a textbox with a very long name. I am trying to replace it with a checkbox dynamically on page load. below is the code. I tried using only the line

```
document.getElementsByName("!SRC!SKU!U_PLANNEDACTIVITY!E!amrit_test_search!U!2")[0].style.display="none"
```

in my javascript but even that is not working. so i guess there is something wrong with

```
document.getElementsByName()


        <html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
    //var a="!SRC!SKU!U_PLANNEDACTIVITY!E!amrit_test_search!U!2";
     var myElement = document.createElement('<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike" id="checkPub"/>');
     document.getElementsByName("!SRC!SKU!U_PLANNEDACTIVITY!E!amrit_test_search!U!2")[0].insertAdjacentElement('afterEnd', myElement); 
    document.getElementsByName("!SRC!SKU!U_PLANNEDACTIVITY!E!amrit_test_search!U!2")[0].style.display="none";



    });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <input type="text" name="!SRC!SKU!U_PLANNEDACTIVITY!E!amrit_test_search!U!2" value="1"  />
    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use document.createElement like that!

Check: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.createElement

So you'll need something like this:

```
var myElement = document.createElement('input');
myElement.type = "checkbox";
myElement.name = "vehicle";
myElement.value = "Bike";
myElement.id = "checkPub";
```

also it wouldn't hurt to look up the element only once, and store the string in a variable:

```
var a="!SRC!SKU!U_PLANNEDACTIVITY!E!amrit_test_search!U!2";
var origelem = document.getElementsByName(a)[0];
origelem.insertAdjacentElement('afterEnd', myElement);
origelem.style.display="none";
```

also you seem to be using jQuery (judging from `$(document).ready(...`). If you are not using jQuery try something like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function onLoad() {
            var a="!SRC!SKU!U_PLANNEDACTIVITY!E!amrit_test_search!U!2";
            var myElement = document.createElement('input');
            myElement.type = "checkbox";
            myElement.name = "vehicle";
            myElement.value = "Bike";
            myElement.id = "checkPub";
            var origelem = document.getElementsByName(a)[0];
            origelem.insertAdjacentElement('afterEnd', myElement);
            origelem.style.display="none";
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="onLoad()">
        <input type="text" name="!SRC!SKU!U_PLANNEDACTIVITY!E!amrit_test_search!U!2" value="1"  />
    </body>
</html>
```

Hope this works for you.

Also learn to DEBUG. Use chrome developer tools of firebug or similar. There is a console telling you about errors.

EDIT: insertAdjacentElement will only work in IE and chrome. A simple

```
origelem.parentNode.appendChild(myElement);
```

is a good substitute for this.

Comment: Its working after a small change but only in ie and chrome not with mozilla :(. Just a small change
 <body onload="onLoad()">
        <input type="text" name="!SRC!SKU!U_PLANNEDACTIVITY!E!amrit_test_search!U!2" value="1"  />
    </body>
</html>

Comment: I see. After using google I found that this function is not implemented in ff. There are alternatives however. I'll whip up a function for you.